# variables in jquery each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

can anybody help me ? - >

I wont that vars id,zIndex,width  inside function after jQuery.each will be defined
and their values will be values from array passed to function MyFunction:

```
console.log(id);  //ID IS NOT DEFINED  
console.log(zIndex);  //NOT DEFINED  
console.log(width);  //NOT DEFINED
```

many thanks for help, Peter

Code>

```
var MyArray = new Object();
MyArray.id = "3";
MyArray.zIndex = "3";
MyArray.width = "600";

function MyFunction(my_array) {

console.log(my_array.id);  //IT IS OK, id is defined    

jQuery.each(my_array, function(key,value) {
    alert(key + " = " + value);
    eval("var" + key + " = " + value); //??????? 


});

console.log(id);  //ID IS NOT DEFINED
console.log(zIndex);  //NOT DEFINED
console.log(width);  //NOT DEFINED

}

MyFunction(MyArray);
```

-----UPDATED ----------------------

THANKS ALL FOR ANSWER 
IN THE MEANTIME I UPDATED MY CODE, 
I WONT TO CREATE SMALL PLUGIN FOR MY APPLICATION
METHOD OPENWINDOW IS PUBLIC

MY QUESTION IS HOW CAN I USE METHOD

```
jQuery.each(my_array, function(key,value) {
 window[key]=value;
});
```

IN PLUGIN PUBLIC METHOD OPENWINDOW

HERE IS CODE IN MORE COMPLEX:

```
    (function($){
    $.fn.MyPlugin = function(options) {

            ...... CODE

            this.OpenWindow = function(my_array) {

            //this way dont work for me here, vars are not defined
            var window = $(window);
                    jQuery.each(my_array, function(key,value) {
                window[key]=value;
            });


                    //VARS ARE NOT DEFINED
                    console.log(id); 
            console.log(zIndex);
            console.log(width);


               //this way work well
                for (var k in my_array){
                    eval ("var " + k + " = " + my_array[k]);
                }

                        //VARS ARE DEFINED
                console.log(id); 
                console.log(zIndex);
                console.log(width);


            .... code

     return this;
    };
    })(jQuery);

var MyArray = new Object();
MyArray.id = "3";
MyArray.zIndex = "3";
MyArray.width = "600";


var MyPlugin = $.fn.MyPlugin();
MyPlugin.OpenWindow(MyArray);
```

Comment: So, use `console.log(my_array.id)` you don't have any variable named `id`

Comment: why you are not using `my_array.id; my_array.zIndex; my_array.width;`?

Comment: id,Zindex and width are not variables they are the properties,so why you are not using my_array.id; my_array.zIndex; my_array.width;?

Comment: i wont to loop over all options(is in array) passed to function becasuse there can be many paramteres passed  instead of declare all options separatelly, I HAVE UPDATED MY CODE... sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of doing it in jquery.each, directly iterate the object you passed using for loop and use eval.

```
var MyArray = new Object();
MyArray.id = "3";
MyArray.zIndex = "3";
MyArray.width = "600";

function MyFunction(my_array) {
    for (var k in my_array){
        eval ("var " + k + " = " + my_array[k]);
    }
    console.log(id); 
    console.log(zIndex);
    console.log(width);

}

MyFunction(MyArray);
```

Comment: thanks for answer it works in my plugin, too,... I have updated my code more complex as you can see

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 $.each(my_array,function(i,n){
    window[i]=n;
})
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2akfv/).

Your way is not work because the `eval` code still run in the each loop of jQuery,so the

variable will be undefined outside the area.

Comment: Thank to both for answer, it works in javascript function well, how can I use this method window[i]=n; inside my plugin method? ... se my updated code..question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of...

```
eval("var" + key + " = " + value);
```

Use

```
window[key] = value;
```

But then id,zIndex and width will become global variables. So you'll have to delete them if you do not want any conflict.